# Server.UrlEncode vs. HttpUtility.UrlEncode

Tags: asp.net, .net, urlencode

Is there a difference between Server.UrlEncode and HttpUtility.UrlEncode?

Answer (score 142, accepted):

`HttpServerUtility.UrlEncode` will use `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` internally. There is no specific difference. The reason for existence of `Server.UrlEncode` is compatibility with classic ASP.

Comment: As for what gets escaped. Internally it calls this function http://referencesource.microsoft.com/#System/net/System/Net/WebUtility.cs,8caf12e95a01d73b

Comment: For readers: Please look at Joel Muller's answer below. That is the most effective way to URL encode: http://stackoverflow.com/a/603962/190476

Answer (score 290):

I had significant headaches with these methods before, **I recommend you *avoid* any variant of `UrlEncode`, and instead use [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx)** - at least that one has a comprehensible behavior.

Let's see...

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(" ") == "+" //breaks ASP.NET when used in paths, non-
                                  //standard, undocumented.
Uri.EscapeUriString("a?b=e") == "a?b=e" // makes sense, but rarely what you
                                        // want, since you still need to
                                        // escape special characters yourself
```

But my personal favorite has got to be **HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode** - this thing is really incomprehensible.  It encodes:

- " " ==> "%20"
- "100% true" ==> "100%%20true" (ok, your url is broken now)
- "test A.aspx#anchor B" ==> "test%20A.aspx**#anchor%20B**"
- "test A.aspx?hmm#anchor B" ==> "test%20A.aspx?hmm**#anchor B**"  (*note the difference with the previous escape sequence!*)

It also has the lovelily specific MSDN documentation "Encodes the path portion of a URL string for reliable HTTP transmission from the Web server to a client." - without actually explaining what it does.  You are less likely to shoot yourself in the foot with an Uzi...

In short, stick to **[Uri.EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx)**.

Comment: And unfortunately that still doesn't work when doing HTTP requests against some web servers -- Uri.EscapeDataString() doesn't encode "!" or "'", which differs from how most browser implementations of escape() work...

Comment: ! and ' characters are not supposed to be encoded; but if a buggy webserver requires this, it's easy to workaround.
Avoid javascript's escape function - it's inherently buggy (impossible to roundtrip, for one).  See http://xkr.us/articles/javascript/encode-compare/ - but in short; you can use encodeUriComponent() instead, which behaves similarly to EscapeDataString - it predictably and reversibly encodes a string, and also does not encode ! and ' characters.

Comment: This is old, but the question got bumped to the front page, so.... The path part of a url string is the part between the domain and the ? or # in a url.

Comment: @R. Bemrose: sure, that is the case: but it doesn't explain the behaviour of UrlPathEncode.  Presumably, it should never corrupt your url (which it does, not encoding %, for instance), and in any case, if your url is already correctly delimited into components by ? and # tokens, what's the point of further encoding?  If the url path contains tokens that need encoding, then it's obviously not safe to pass the entire url to the encoding function - that's an invalid and perhaps corrupted url, almost by definition.  In short, the function isn't specified and its most reasonable use is impossible.

Comment: UrlPathEncode doesn't touch anything after the ? because it assumes the query string is already encoded.  I'm guessing it also doesn't encode characters like % in order to avoid breaking existing encodings.  E.g., if I have "a b" encoded as "a%20b", UrlEncode("a%20b") gives "a%2520b" (equivalent to "a%20b", which is wrong), whereas UrlPathEncode just gives "a%20b" (which is right).

Comment: That said, I'm not when you'd use UrlPathEncode except if the only thing you want to encode is spaces (and they don't occur after a  `?`).  And it's not good that some of the documentation incorrectly claims that it encodes characters like `?`, `&` and `/` (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urlpathencode(v=VS.100).aspx) and some misleadingly makes it sound like it only differs from UrlEncode in how it encodes spaces (http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.urlpathencode.aspx)

Comment: @Tim: there might be several `?` and who's to say which are to be encoded and which serve as separators?  As to the space: in both cases the space is in the hash, so the presence or absence of a query-fragment shouldn't matter.  And finally, it's inexcusable to corrupt an Uri as in the second example containing a %.  The `UrlPathEncode` method is plain borked and should never be used.

Comment: I think my answer at http://stackoverflow.com/a/13993486/237091 may shed a little light on the intended usage of UrlEncode/UrlPathEncode.

Comment: I also ran into these issues in Java. It's dumbfounding to think that something so essential can be so convoluted in todays age.

Comment: @alexangas: You just linked to precisely one of the borked methods :-) - kinda proves the point how confusing the .net api is here.

Comment: @ScottStafford After I figured out what `UrlEncode` is for, I came here to post that but it looks like you've already done it. One thing to add is if you're using it outside a web application then you should use `System.Net.WebUtility` instead.

Comment: Late to the party, but after a bit of research I now think there's two problems here. RFC 1866 defined that the query string of URLs should be application/x-www-form-urlencoded. So if you're encoding a URL, the space should be a "%20" BEFORE the "?", and a "+" when it's part of the query string (meaning real "+" characters become "%2b".

In retrospect, that feels like someone made a mistake in the definition...

Comment: @zippy72 is right, the HTML standard specifies application/x-www-form-urlencoded for encoding after the "?".  See "Mutate action URL" and "application/x-www-form-urlencoded serializer" in the HTML standard. These specify encoding space as "+" in the query string after the "?".

Answer (score 91):

Fast-forward almost 9 years since this was first asked, and in the world of .NET Core and .NET Standard, it seems the most common options we have for URL-encoding are **WebUtility.UrlEncode** (under `System.Net`) and **Uri.EscapeDataString**. Judging by the most popular answer here and elsewhere, **Uri.EscapeDataString** appears to be preferable. But is it? I did some analysis to understand the differences and here's what I came up with:

- `WebUtility.UrlEncode` encodes space as `+`; `Uri.EscapeDataString` encodes it as `%20`.
- `Uri.EscapeDataString` percent-encodes `!`, `(`, `)`, and `*`; `WebUtility.UrlEncode` does not.
- `WebUtility.UrlEncode` percent-encodes `~`; `Uri.EscapeDataString` does not.
- `Uri.EscapeDataString` throws a `UriFormatException` on strings longer than 65,520 characters; `WebUtility.UrlEncode` does not. ([A more common problem than you might think, particularly when dealing with URL-encoded form data](https://github.com/dotnet/corefx/issues/1936).)
- `Uri.EscapeDataString` throws a `UriFormatException` on the [high surrogate characters](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/xcwwfbb8.aspx); `WebUtility.UrlEncode` does not. (That's a UTF-16 thing, probably a lot less common.)

For URL-encoding purposes, characters fit into one of 3 categories: unreserved (legal in a URL); reserved (legal in but has special meaning, so you *might* want to encode it); and everything else (must always be encoded).

According to the [RFC](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc3986#section-2), the reserved characters are: `:/?#[]@!$&'()*+,;=`

And the unreserved characters are alphanumeric and `-._~`

### The Verdict

**Uri.EscapeDataString** clearly defines its mission: %-encode all reserved and illegal characters. **WebUtility.UrlEncode** is more ambiguous in both definition and implementation. Oddly, it encodes some reserved characters but not others (why parentheses and not brackets??), and stranger still it encodes that innocently unreserved `~` character.

Therefore, I concur with the popular advice - use **Uri.EscapeDataString** when possible, and understand that reserved characters like `/` and `?` will get encoded. If you need to deal with potentially large strings, particularly with URL-encoded form content, you'll need to either fall back on **WebUtility.UrlEncode** and accept its quirks, or otherwise work around the problem.

---

**EDIT:** I've [attempted](https://github.com/tmenier/Flurl/issues/262) to rectify ALL of the quirks mentioned above in [Flurl](https://flurl.io) via the `Url.Encode`, `Url.EncodeIllegalCharacters`, and `Url.Decode` static methods. These are in the [core package](https://www.nuget.org/packages/Flurl) (which is tiny and doesn't include all the HTTP stuff), or feel free to rip them from the source. I welcome any comments/feedback you have on these.

---

Here's the code I used to discover which characters are encoded differently:

```
var diffs =
    from i in Enumerable.Range(0, char.MaxValue + 1)
    let c = (char)i
    where !char.IsHighSurrogate(c)
    let diff = new {
        Original = c,
        UrlEncode = WebUtility.UrlEncode(c.ToString()),
        EscapeDataString = Uri.EscapeDataString(c.ToString()),
    }
    where diff.UrlEncode != diff.EscapeDataString
    select diff;

foreach (var diff in diffs)
    Console.WriteLine($"{diff.Original}\t{diff.UrlEncode}\t{diff.EscapeDataString}");
```

Comment: This is brilliant!

Comment: Great job verifying the suggested solution on the modern .net framework.

Comment: It should be mentioned that there are some differences between **WebUtility** and **HttpUtility**. **WebUtility** is using uppercase and **HttpUtility** is using lowercase for hexa entities. In addition **HttpUtility** was not included in old subset versions of .NET Framework "Client Profile". **WebUtility** is available from .NET Framework 4.0.

Comment: .NET Fiddle of the above code with `WebUtility.UrlEncode`, `Uri.EscapeDataString`, `Uri.EscapeUriString` and `HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode`: https://dotnetfiddle.net/Bo51qR

Comment: As of at least .NET 4.8 (not sure where/when the change was introduced), `Uri.EscapeDataString("")` will correctly encode as 4 UTF-8 octects, showing that this method is currently Unicode-outside-of-BMP safe. Also, [MSDN now documents the maximum input length as 32k, not 64k](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapedatastring?view=netframework-4.8) (same for .NET Framework 4.8 and .NET Core+)

Answer (score 31):

Keep in mind that you probably shouldn't be using either one of those methods. Microsoft's [Anti-Cross Site Scripting Library](https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=28589) includes replacements for `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` and `HttpUtility.HtmlEncode` that are both more standards-compliant, and more secure. As a bonus, you get a `JavaScriptEncode` method as well.

Comment: After reading the documentation and FAQ on the link provided, I believe this answer is the best and most secure way to encode data! Thanks a ton for sharing this!

Comment: The link doesn't work any more. What are the replacement methods?

Comment: @EdwardBrey This is the latest version of Anti-Cross site scripting library: https://www.microsoft.com/en-au/download/details.aspx?id=28589

Comment: Please include the answer in your answer. Broken links are not very helpful. I think you're hinting at `System.Web.Security.AntiXss.AntiXssEncoder.UrlEncode` which is *yet another* method of encoding.

Comment: It looks like the output of `AntiXssEncoder.UrlEncode` is equal to that of `Uri.EscapeDataString` but the code doesn't depend on `Uri.EscapeDataString` as far as I can tell.

Comment: @SudhanshuMishra Your link becomes broken links also......

Answer (score 11):

Server.UrlEncode() is there to provide backward compatibility with Classic ASP,

```
Server.UrlEncode(str);
```

Is equivalent to:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode(str, Response.ContentEncoding);
```

Answer (score 5):

The same, `Server.UrlEncode()` calls `HttpUtility.UrlEncode()`