# Server.UrlEncode vs Uri.EscapeDataString

Tags: .net, encoding

What exactly is the difference between the two functions. The output seems similar except the `Uri.EscapeUriString` encodes spaces to `%20` and `Server.UrlEncode` encodes them as a `+` sign.

And the final question which should be used preferably

Comment: Note that in the title the OP asked about `Uri.EscapeDataString` and in the question he is asking about `Uri.EscapeUriString` they a equivalent.

Comment: I posted a detailed answer to a related question [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877559/62600), and in hindsight it might have been a better fit for this question, although I don't want to double post so hopefully linking to it here will suffice.

Comment: use WebUtility.UrlEncode according to https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877559/579763

Comment: I found that HttpUtility.UrlEncode does not change exclamantion marks to %21 but ri.EscapeDataString does!

Comment: https://gist.github.com/xl1/2d0b2890fa4a70142a41afd4c5bbe215#file-gistfile2-md

Answer (score 36):

If any one will came across this in the future:

After some digging I have found out that `Uri.EscapeDataString` is the preferable option. See the the highest voted answer [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1148326/3992622) and [this](http://geekswithblogs.net/mikehuguet/archive/2009/08/16/134123.aspx) post.

EDIT: Adding the information from the second link here:

> We found that in some cases you need to consider using Uri.EscapeDataString.  In our case we are encrypting the querystring and found that UrlDecode is converting a plus (+) to space.  This was causing us errors during decryption.  Using Uri’s Escape and UnescapeDataString makes sense for us when constructing a custom querystring in the URL.

Comment: You can get an System.UriFormatException on long strings

Comment: http://errorfunx.blogspot.com/2012/12/dont-use-net-systemuriunescapedatastrin.html#:~:text=url%20encoding%20should%20encode%20space%20into%20%22%2B%22%20or%20%22%2520%22.%20url%20decoding%20should%20decode%20%22%2B%22%20or%20%2220%22%20into%20space.%20however%20by%20design%2C%20system.uri.unescapedatastring%20doesn't%20decode%20%22%2B%22%20into%20space.

Answer (score 5):

I found that `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` is tolerant to `null` strings and long strings. It's available both in .NET Core and .NET Framework.

But I also found that `Uri.EscapeDataString` is 4X faster and uses less memory

| Method | Mean | Error | StdDev | Gen0 | Allocated |
| --- | --- | --- | --- | --- | --- |
| EscapeDataString | 19.52 ns | 0.333 ns | 0.018 ns | - | - |
| HttpUtilityUrlEncode | 88.69 ns | 41.303 ns | 2.264 ns | 0.0191 | 120 B |