# Encoding parameters for a URL

Tags: c#, .net, url, silverlight, encoding

I have a Silverlight application that is building a URL. This URL is a call to a REST-based service. This service expects a single parameter that represents a location. The location is in the form of "city, state". To build this URL, I'm calling the following code:

```
string url = "http://www.example.com/myService.svc/";
url += HttpUtility.UrlEncode(locationTextBox.Text);
```

If a user enters "chicago, il" into locationTextBox, the result looks like this:

```
http://www.example.com/myService.svc/chicago%2c+il
```

In reality though, I was kind of expecting the URL to look like;

```
http://www.example.com/myService.svc/chicago,%20il
```

When testing my service via the browser URL, the one I am expecting works. However, the URL that is being generated is not working. What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 106, accepted):

I would recommend [Uri](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/System.Uri.aspx).[EscapeDataString](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx) instead of using [HttpUtility](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httputility.aspx) functions. See discussion in [Server.UrlEncode vs. HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602642/server-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode).

Comment: I tried this and still got the error for '#' character. Pls see    my question here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/31699335/regex-to-validate-a-string-that-will-be-one-of-the-of-wcf-rest-method-url-parame

Answer (score 7):

Try to use the UrlPathEncode() method.
View the remarks at:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/h10z5byc.aspx

Quote:

> You can encode a URL using with the
>   UrlEncode() method or the
>   UrlPathEncode() method. However, the
>   methods return different results. The
>   UrlEncode() method converts each space
>   character to a plus character (+). The
>   UrlPathEncode() method converts each
>   space character into the string "%20",
>   which represents a space in
>   hexadecimal notation. Use the
>   UrlPathEncode() method when you encode
>   the path portion of a URL in order to
>   guarantee a consistent decoded URL,
>   regardless of which platform or
>   browser performs the decoding.

Answer (score 0):

The safest bet is to use the AntiXss library. It has more standard (and secure) versions for encoding contents to various purposes (like Url encodes, Html and HtmlAttribute encodes, and more). 
there's the old 3.1 version available for download from MS site (http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?FamilyId=051ee83c-5ccf-48ed-8463-02f56a6bfc09), which will work with older .NET versions, and the new one at http://wpl.codeplex.com/

Answer (score 0):

Since there isn't an example that actually uses `Uri.EscapeDataString`, I'll add mine.

```cs
using System;

var email = "email@gmail.com";
var url = $"https://api.domain.com/send-email?email={Uri.EscapeDataString(email)}";
```