# C# - How to send search keywords like google

Tags: c#, asp.net, webforms

I want to send search keywords with QueryString like google, atc...
and i need a function which convert text like this

> Metallica nimes concert 2009 :)

to this:

```
Metallica+nimes+concert+2009+%3A%29
```

and retrieve it

Thanks and advance

Comment: Do you just want to encode a string?  I am confused

Comment: This is called URL encoding. It's explained in MSDN, most courses, most examples that show making a GET request with HttpClient, HttpWebRequest or WebClient

Comment: BTW, just *DON'T* use `UrlEncode`. The duplicate explains why

Comment: Related explanation here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1148326/134204

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you need to encode the string using:

```
HttpUtility.UrlEncode("Metallica nimes concert 2009 :)")
```

you'll need to reference to System.Web

This will work on simple strings, if you want to encode more characters see: 
 [Server.UrlEncode vs. HttpUtility.UrlEncode](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602642/server-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode). as  Panagiotis Kanavos recommended

Comment: Don't we have enough duplicates of this already?

Comment: @PanagiotisKanavos Apparently not :')

Comment: How about [check the duplicate to see why this is a bad idea](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095351/encoding-parameters-for-a-url) ? You just added a trap for the next person that tries to encode data

Comment: Slightly happier now?

Answer (score -1):

Trying to encode a string into a URL?

Why not use [`system.net.webutility.urlencode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Docs here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.webutility.urlencode(v=vs.110).aspx)

[Rock here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=nmAI6V6MrQE)

Comment: Posting an answer when there are so many duplicates already doesn't help at all. It only creates adds noise and makes it *harder* to find an answer

Comment: It helps the person asking the question... it also allowed me to make the little docs here rocks here thing which pleased me.

Comment: That's what the search button is for. In fact, are you *sure* you should use that function at all? Check the duplicate to see [why you shouldn't](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5095351/encoding-parameters-for-a-url)