# How to unescape a URL in MVC 3

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-3, url, escaping

I've got a raw text string in the form:

```
http://www.site.com/abc/%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI5N2ARPTHQHTRGMA%26creative%3D165953%26creative%3DB0058RECN6
```

Are there any built in utilities to unescape those characters?

I'm using ASP.NET MVC 3

Comment: You may want to look at this post on the different methods... http://stackoverflow.com/questions/602642/server-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this below

```
var  decodedString = System.Web.HttpUtility.UrlDecode("http://www.site.com/abc/%3FSubscriptionId%3DAKIAI5N2ARPTHQHTRGMA%26creative%3D165953%26creative%3DB0058RECN6");
```

Answer (score 3):

The [`HttpUtility.UrlDecode`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.httpserverutility.urldecode.aspx) method should do it for you.

Comment: Not sure how to use this as it's not a static method and you cannot instantiate the class since it has no public ctor's?