# how to remove validate input parameters on a action?

Tags: asp.net-mvc-4, model-view-controller

i want to redirect from on page to another on mvc and pass some parameter and get them on second page.

my parameter is something like this

```
?id=UXodaA54Iqo+gId3avkIqA
```

but when i get this parameter on the second the page some characters like "+" removed
and the parameter has been changed to this

```
    UXodaA54Iqo gId3avkIqA
```

my action is

```
    [ValidateInput(false)] 
    public ActionResult test(string id)
    {
        return view();
     }
```

what is the best way to handle it just for this action because i do not want to put some thing like this on my web config

```
  <httpRuntime requestValidationMode="2.0" />
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is not releated to validation. A `+` character in a query string parameter is seen as a space. Use [`HttpUtility.UrlPathEncode()` to encode your parameter](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602642/server-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode).