# Query string with "+" symbol contains space when passed to another page

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

Before passing the query to another page it contains argument

> UwHe6N8aN0ZAHhestx+adQ==

But when passed, the receiving page got

> UwHe6N8aN0ZAHhestx adQ==

value instead.

The "+" got auto converted to space.

[image]

How can I stop the auto conversion of the query parameters?

Comment: are you use '+' in query string?

Comment: You need to [UrlEncode](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/4fkewx0t(v=vs.110).aspx) you data

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you should correctly [UrlEncode](http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp) that string:

```
var str = "UwHe6N8aN0ZAHhestx+adQ==";
Console.WriteLine(Uri.EscapeDataString(str));
```

Or, taking into account that it seems to be ASP.NET application, you can use [`HttpContext.Current.Server.UrlEncode`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/zttxte6w(v=vs.110).aspx) [instead](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602642/server-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode).

Comment: @TiongGor If this answer helped you, you may [accept it](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/5234/how-does-accepting-an-answer-work).