# Using %ad in a string for 'Like' operator to filter query results

Tags: c#, asp.net, sql-server, visual-studio-2010

I have a query that retrieves some info from a database on a mssql server like this:

```
String sql = "select Name from Projects where Name NOT IN (select Project_Name from vDays) and Name like @filterText order by Name";
```

I have a textbox that lets the user enter some text to filter the Projects returned by name when using % symbol before, after, or surrounding the text. This works fine except when the user enters anything beginning with `%ad`. When this happens, the debugger (using VS2010) shows the text as `�`. This of course gets passed into the query and doesn't return the right info.

I've done a bunch of googling and can't find any reason why `%ad` transforms into `�`. So far, every other query has worked fine.

Update:

Okay, so the change happens when I'm going to a different page using `Response.Redirect` and sending the textbox value with it.

```
filterText = FilterTextBox.Text;
Response.Redirect("UnusedProjects_Results.aspx?filterText=" + filterText);
```

`filterText` shows `%ad` properly.

Then on the next page:

```
string filterText = "";
filterText = Request.QueryString["filterText"];
```

`filterText` shows `�`

As @DavidT.Macknet said in the comment, this seems to be because of URL encoding. Is there a way to keep those % symbols there without being encoded? If not, I can always change it so the user enters `*` instead, then replace all `*` with `%` before the queries happen.

Comment: That's a URL-encoded value, maybe? http://www.w3schools.com/tags/ref_urlencode.asp

Comment: Shoot, yeah looks like that is it. Going to update my question. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to encode the `filterText` on the line

```
Response.Redirect("UnusedProjects_Results.aspx?filterText=" + filterText);
```

with uri encoding. A good tool to do this is with [`Uri.EscapeDataString`](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.uri.escapedatastring.aspx), it is [more reliable](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602642/server-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode) than using `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` which is what you will see most code examples using.

```
Response.Redirect("UnusedProjects_Results.aspx?filterText=" + Uri.EscapeDataString(filterText));
```

This will encode the `%` symbol so it gets parsed correctly after the redirect happens.