# ASP.net not catching QueryString

Tags: c#, asp.net, query-string

I have created a ASP.net application,where i change the language base on its query string.
I have two servers both are https ,but one is redirected by netscaler

```
https://testMyLiveCode.com
https://myNetscalerServer.com/testapply-aU4uC6Q9dU94nHzVZA6zdtaQE433Xa2a/?
```

For eg

https://testMyLiveCode.com/?ln=en

This is my asp.net code

```
string strNewLanguage = Request.QueryString["ln"].ToLower();
SessionHelper.Language = strNewLanguage ;
string strNewURL = Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Replace("ln=" + Request.QueryString["ln"], "");
 Response.Redirect(strNewURL);
```

What i actually do is that change the language depending on querystring and change the querystring and redirects

THis works perfectly with my https Server

https://testMyLiveCode.com/?ln=en

But this doesnt work with my netscaler url

```
https://myNetscalerServer.com/testapply-aU4uC6Q9dU94nHzVZA6zdtaQE433Xa2a/?
```

This is my url

And after i added the querystring to it,it does not work
https://myNetscalerServer.com/testapply-aU4uC6Q9dU94nHzVZA6zdtaQE433Xa2a/??ln=en

Can anyone help why this is not working as the url already has a ? in it???
 Thanks for any help

Comment: `https://myNetscalerServer.com/testapply-aU4uC6Q9dU94nHzVZA6zdtaQE433Xa2a/?` you have already aquestion mark at the end ??

Comment: tried with only one '?' ????

Comment: Ya tried with only one it shows error

Comment: `testapply-aU4uC6Q9dU94nHzVZA6z‌​dtaQE433Xa2a/?` where did that string come from? Who / what told you to use that?

Comment: @mjwills - its an id generated by netscaller

Comment: I suspect you should UrlEncode that value @ParshuramKalvikatte . https://stackoverflow.com/questions/602642/server-urlencode-vs-httputility-urlencode

Comment: Ohh thats a valid point ,ok i will give a try..

Answer (score 0):

My suggestion is to change the string which contains '?', it you can't then below instruction and code might help you
 I am writing below code  based on language array, you need to modify this based on your requirement, Hopefully this will help.It's bad code you have to modify this to make this good

```
string[] obj = new string[5] {"hi","en","ar","or","xy" };            
        string urlString = Request.RawUrl.ToLower();
        int location = 0;
        for (int i = 0; i < obj.Length; i++)
        {
            if (urlString.Contains("=" + obj[i]))
            {
                location = i;
                break;
            }
        }
        string strNewURL = Request.RawUrl.ToLower().Replace("ln=" + obj[location], "");
        Response.Redirect(strNewURL);
```