# HttpUtility.UrlEncode with uppercase hex characters

Tags: c#, urlencode

`HttpUtility.UrlEncode("abc : 123")` produces `abc+%3a+123` but I need it to produce `abc+%3A+123` (notice the uppercase `A`.

Is there a way to have UrlEncode output uppercase hex characters?

I don't want to simply call `.ToUpper()` on the entire string because I need `abc` to stay lowercase.

Comment: This post may help (https://stackoverflow.com/questions/575440/url-encoding-using-c-sharp), `HttpUtility.UrlEncode` will transform a colon into %3a lowercase, if you need the upper case A, I believe you may need to use a different utility for your encoding, the provided post shows the output of encoding from different C# classes. I believe from the provided tables in the post that you may want to use `WebUtility.UrlEncode(string)`

Answer (score 2):

I believe I've found the answer from the 2nd answer in this question: https://stackoverflow.com/a/1148326/20471

The solution is to use `Uri.EscapeDataString` because it uses `%20` for spaces instead of `+` and also uppercases the hex replacements.

Answer (score 1):

This is not supported out of the box, but you can do it yourself:

```
private static string UrlEncodeUpperCase(string stringToEncode)
{
    var reg = new Regex(@"%[a-f0-9]{2}");
    stringToEncode = HttpUtility.UrlEncode(stringToEncode);
    return reg.Replace(stringToEncode, m => m.Value.ToUpperInvariant());
}
```

Keep in mind that `[RFC 3986][1]` explicitly mentions that uppercase and lowercase are equivalent.

Comment: They're not equivalent though when it comes to auth signatures, unfortunately