# vb .net base64 not encoding correctly

Tags: php, .net, json, vb.net, base64

I have looked all over and none of the issues I am finding fixes my issue.

I have a program that sends json strings to a server.  I upload and download files.  They are between a vb client and php server.  I can go from the server to the client just fine but when I try to send a file to the server the base64 is invalid.

Here is my code on the vb side.

```vb
Dim bytes As Byte()
bytes = System.IO.File.ReadAllBytes(filename)

Dim base64String As String = Convert.ToBase64String(bytes)
```

If I send a text file and decode it manually 80% of the file is there then it just goes to garbage.  Is there some other setting for convert.tobase64String that I'm missing?

Here is the base64 inside the json

> 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 QmFjayBVcCAoRnVsbCkgLSBFdmVyeSBkYXkgaWYgcG9zc2libGUsIGFmdGVyIGhvdXJzLg0KIA==

Here is the textfile that made it.

```
This knowledge base article should have the maintenance plan that David is referencing.

https://supportcenter.emds.com/articles/Troubleshooting/How-do-I-reindex-my-Solution-Series-80-database&s=reindex%20&p=1 

If you have any questions about it please feel free to give us a call at the IT department (1-800-565-5564 option 2)

-Art

    December 5, 2017 · Like0 · Dislike0 · Flag

Casey WilliamsCasey Williams
Hey Jim,

I know this is super old, but if you're still looking for an answer - you should NEVER Shrink the Database unless absolutely needed. 

Here is a correct list of Maintenance Plans and how often the should run:
Backup Log Files of all DB: Every 30 Minutes
Primary Maintenance Plan: Check Database Integrity>Rebuild Index>Back Up (Full) - Every day if possible, after hours.
```

Here is what comes out on the server side

```
This knowledge base article should have the maintenance plan that David is referencing.

https://supportcenter.emds.com/articles/Troubleshooting/How-do-I-reindex-my-Solution-Series-80-database&s=reindex%20&p=1

If you have any questions about it please feel free to give us a call at the IT department (1-800-565-5564 option 2)

-Art

    December 5, 2017 · Like0 · Dislike0 · Flag

Casey WilliamsCasey Williams Hey Jim,

I know this is super old, but if you're still looking for an answer - you should NEVER Shrink the Database unless absolutely needed.

Here is a correct list of Maintenance Plans and how often the should run: Backup Log Files of all DB: Every 30 Minutes Primary Maintenance Plan: Check Database Integrity>Rebuild Indexbase64: invalid input
```

Comment: You have included PHP tag, and I see why you did it, but in fact this question has rather nothing to do with PHP, which is a little bit misleading.

Comment: I am sending this to php and the decode on it just sends out a blank.  base64 on the server at least gives some info.

Comment: This is not the output I get from a base64 conversion of your sample text. The base64 string you have posted is not correct (wrong termination), it also includes a line break near the end. Check out the serialization procedure.

Comment: That Base64 string is broken. There is a space character near the end. If I remove it, then it's an invalid length. If replace it with a legal character, I get the expected output.

Comment: The correct Base64 string has a '/' character where the white space is in the question, and that's the only '/' present. It's likely being stripped during construction of the HTTP request. The string needs to be encoded or escaped in some fashion to avoid that.

Comment: Yes I know the base64 is broken.  That is why I am asking for help.  Microsoft .net is outputing wrong base64.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use [`Uri.EscapeDataString()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.uri.escapedatastring?view=netframework-4.7.2) to encode your Base64 string as body data. This will encode the slash as `%2F` and should be automatically decoded by the server.

```vb
Dim encodedString As String = Uri.EscapeDataString(base64String)
```

**EDIT:**

For data longer than 65520 chars you can use [`WebUtility.UrlEncode()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.net.webutility.urlencode?view=netframework-4.7.2) instead until the `Uri` class's problem is fixed (if it ever will be), but note that `WebUtility` too has [some quirks of its own](https://stackoverflow.com/a/47877559).

```vb
Dim encodedString As String = WebUtility.UrlEncode(base64String)
```

`Uri.EscapeDataString()` is the most RFC-compliant method today and thus is the preferred solution (when possible).

Comment: That works for small amounts of data.  Is there something like this that does not have a very small limit?

Comment: @darkstar2002 : I have edited my answer to include an alternate solution. Note that `Uri.EscapeDataString()` is the preferred solution whenever possible, though.

Comment: @darkstar2002 : Glad I could help! Good luck with your project!